# "The method is not defined for the type" error in simple program in java

Tags: java

So I'm just trying to learn Java and after watching some tutorials and reading some basic stuff I am stuck about why this won't run:

```
package Test;

public class TestProg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fetch fetc = new Fetch();
        fetc.more(10, 20);
    }
}
```

This is the Fetch class  code:

```
package Test;

public class Fetch {

    public Fetch() {

        System.out.println("Fetched!"); 

        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c;

        while (a < 100 && b < 200) {
            a++;
            b++;
            c = a + b;
            System.out.println(c);
        }

        public void more(int d, int e) {
            System.out.println(d + e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting a "The method more(int, int) is not defined for the type Fetch" error in TestProg. If I remove the code about the "more" method (in both Classes), the rest of the code runs normally. I am stumped as to why this would happen because the code is extremely similar to the example I'm studying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method `more(int d, int e)` is within the `Fetch()` constructor

Your fetch method should be as follows (note the marked `}` closing the constructor):

```
package Test;

public class Fetch {



    public Fetch() {

        System.out.println("Fetched!"); 

        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c;

        while (a < 100 && b < 200) {

            a++;
            b++;
            c = a + b;
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }//<---- NOTE: closing constructor


    public void more(int d, int e) {

        System.out.println(d + e);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

`more` should be located **outside** the constructor.

That's why indentation is extremely important.. Together we'll make the planet a better place to live in - Indent your code :)

Comment: Interestingly it was indented (I copied it over into my IDE) but with some kind of bizarre space that was automatically overtyped and clearly ignored by stack overflow

Comment: @RichardTingle Yes.. Happens to me sometimes. Anyway, try to indent it here as well so we can better understand your code.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have declared your `more` method within the `Fetch` constructor.

This should not compile, nor make the method accessible from outside the class.

To fix this, add one closing curly bracket before the `more` method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing } after the while loop. There is a clue in that this class would also show up as having errors!

Answer (score 1):

`More` must be located outside the `fetch` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented the `more(int, int)`  method within your `Fetch()  constructor`. Please verify `{` and `}`

current code

```
class  Fetch {
   public Fetch() {
        public void more(int d, int e) {
            System.out.println(d + e);
         }
    }
}
```

need to change to like below

```
class  Fetch {
   public Fetch() {

    }
    public void more(int d, int e) {
            System.out.println(d + e);
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**more**  should be outside the constructor and more over you are missing the close braces ///

Answer (score 1):

Replace your Fetch class with below, you have some issues with braces in class:

```
class Fetch {

    public Fetch() {

        System.out.println("Fetched!");

        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c;

        while (a < 100 && b < 200) {

            a++;
            b++;
            c = a + b;
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }

    public void more(int d, int e) {

        System.out.println(d + e);
    }

}
```