# Java problem - method undefined even though I already defined it in the package

Tags: java

I'm a total beginner in Java and I'm working on an assignment that's largely prefabricated/preformatted code, but I can't get it to work. In Eclipse, I get an error saying "**Method cardToString(MyCard) is undefined for the type MyCardTester**" before I even run it. I've looked at similar questions on Stackoverflow,

([Eclipse is telling me a method is undefined when it clearly is in fact defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671789/eclipse-is-telling-me-a-method-is-undefined-when-it-clearly-is-in-fact-defined), ["The method is not defined for the type" error in simple program in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889827/the-method-is-not-defined-for-the-type-error-in-simple-program-in-java))

and they have different problems from me. I think that my problem may be with my classpath or run configuration, but those settings seem fine. Here is the code:

Here's the first class:

```
package EllevensGame;
import EllevensGame.MyCard;
import java.lang.String;

/**
 * This is a class that tests the Card class.
 */

public class MyCardTester {

    /**
     * The main method in this class checks the Card operations for consistency.
     *  @param args is not used.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyCard testCard = new MyCard("King", "Hearts", 13);
        String printStuff = cardToString(testCard);
        System.out.println(printStuff);
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
package EllevensGame;
/**
 * MyCard.java
 *
 * <code>MyCard</code> represents a playing card.
 */
import java.lang.String;

public class MyCard {

    /**
     * String value that holds the suit of the card
     */
    protected String suit;

    /**
     * String value that holds the rank of the card
     */
    protected String rank;

    /**
     * int value that holds the point value.
     */
    protected int pointValue;


   /**
     * Creates a new <code>Card</code> instance.
     *
     * @param cardRank  a <code>String</code> value
     *                  containing the rank of the card
     * @param cardSuit  a <code>String</code> value
     *                  containing the suit of the card
     * @param cardPointValue an <code>int</code> value
     *                  containing the point value of the card
     */
    public MyCard(String cardRank, String cardSuit, int cardPointValue) {
        //MyCard newCard = new MyCard(cardRank, cardSuit, cardPointValue); Not sure if this is right or not 
    }


    /**
     * Accesses this <code>Card's</code> suit.
     * @return this <code>Card's</code> suit.
     */
    public String suit() {
        return suit;
   }

    /**
     * Accesses this <code>Card's</code> rank.
     * @return this <code>Card's</code> rank.
     */
    public String rank() {
        return rank;
    }

   /**
     * Accesses this <code>Card's</code> point value.
     * @return this <code>Card's</code> point value.
     */
    public int pointValue() {
        return pointValue;
    }

    /** Compare this card with the argument.
     * @param otherCard the other card to compare to this
     * @return true if the rank, suit, and point value of this card
     *              are equal to those of the argument;
     *         false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean matches(MyCard otherCard) {
        if (otherCard.pointValue == (pointValue()) && (otherCard.rank.equals(rank)) && (otherCard.suit.equals(suit))) {
            return true;
        }
        else {return false;}
    }

    /**
     * Converts the rank, suit, and point value into a string in the format
     *     "[Rank] of [Suit] (point value = [PointValue])".
     * This provides a useful way of printing the contents
     * of a <code>Deck</code> in an easily readable format or performing
     * other similar functions.
     *
     * @return a <code>String</code> containing the rank, suit,
     *         and point value of the card.
     */
    //@Override
    public String cardToString(MyCard newCard) {
        String pointstring = String.valueOf(pointValue);
        String print = rank + " of " + suit + pointstring;
        return print;
    }
}
```

Final note: the code is supposed to create a "card" object for a card game (Ellevens).

Thanks!!

Comment: `String printStuff = testCard.cardToString(testCard);` That method has an unused and unneeded parameter though. Maybe you added that?

Comment: You need to invoke the method on an instance of the class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cardToString` is a method in `MyCard`, you **must** invoke it through the reference. Change

```
String printStuff = cardToString(testCard);
```

to

```
String printStuff = testCard.cardToString(testCard);
```

Although it might be better to make that method return a `String` based on the `this` instance (which would make more sense).

```
public String cardToString() {
    return rank + " of " + suit + pointValue;
}
```

And then

```
String printStuff = testCard.cardToString();
```

I then fixed your constructor

```
public MyCard(String cardRank, String cardSuit, int cardPointValue) {
    this.rank = cardRank;
    this.suit = cardSuit;
    this.pointValue = cardPointValue;
}
```

And ran it getting

```
King of Hearts13
```

Comment: Still get that error? **Not** `Method cardToString(MyCard) is undefined for the type MyCardTester`? Have you recompiled your code?

Comment: Yes the error is a run-time error now. Sorry for staying "still"

Comment: Well I fixed your constructor and ran it, and it works fine here. I suggest you try again.

Comment: @Brandon_J Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean) thread

Comment: Holy moly I got it to work!! Fixed it based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162773/how-do-i-add-a-directory-to-the-eclipse-classpath - I had a random (unnecessary) file required in the build path. Thank you so much!!